# About cross product, differentiation and perpendicular vectors

Tags: calculus

I have the following problem.

$\vec{r} (t)$ is a twice-differentiable vector function and $\vec{B}$ is a fixed vector with magnitude $4$. The cross product between $\vec{r} (t)$ and $\vec{B}$ is $4t \hat{i}$ for all t.

If vector $\vec{r}'(t)$ is perpendicular to vector $\vec{B}$. Determine if vectors $\vec{r}'(t)$ and $\vec{r}'' (t)$ are perpendicular.

I know that $4t \hat{i}$ is orthogonal to vectors $\vec{r}(t)$ and $B$, and that if a differentiable vector has constant length then the vector and its first derivative are orthogonal.

Could you please show me an example or give any tips on how to solve this?

Please excuse my english. Thanks.

Comment: The cross product is a vector. How can it be equal 4t?

Comment: @GReyes Intention was presumably $\vec{r}\times \vec{B}=4t\hat{i}=(4t,0,0)$

Comment: Just guessing: $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{B}$ are both in the y,z-plane. If $\vec{r}' \perp \vec{B}$, then $\vec{r}' \parallel \vec{r}$. Hence $\vec{r}'' \parallel \vec{r}'  \parallel \vec{r}$

Comment: @Semiclassical Yes that was my intention, thank you for correcting my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the second derivative in your relation you get
$$
r''\times B+2r'\times B'+r\times B''=0
$$
Since $B$ is fixed, the last two terms disappear and hence $r''\times B=0$. Therefore $r''$ is parallel to $B$ and (given that $r'$ is perpendicular to $B$), it is perpendicular to $r'$.

I do not see any need for the condition $|B|=4$.

Comment: +1, beat me ...

Comment: @GReyes Thank you very much